# Using sets and SetHasSize on intersections in z3

Tags: z3, z3py

I've been trying to enumerate solutions to the [following problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833059/finding-sets-that-satisfy-intersection-cardinalities). I've started with simple approach first.

Below I have two sets of size `k`, intersection between them is of size 1 and I want to see how sets `A` and `B` look:

```py
Els, elems = EnumSort('Els',['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])
A, B = Consts('A B', SetSort(Els))
k, c = Ints('k c')
s = Solver()
s.add(SetHasSize(A, k))
s.add(SetHasSize(B, k))
s.add(k == 2, c == 1)
s.add(SetHasSize(SetIntersect(A, B), c))
s.check()
s.model()
```

Here, the solution should be `A == ['a1', 'a2']` and `B == ['a2', 'a3']` but satisfiability was not reached.

Even a simple task like one below results in never ending execution:

```py
V, _ = EnumSort('Els',['a1', 'a2', 'a3'])
A = Const('A', SetSort(V))
k = Int('k')
s = SimpleSolver()
s.add(SetHasSize(A, k))
s.add(k == IntVal(2))
s.check()
s.model()
```

Changing `k == IntVal(2)` to `k <= IntVal(2)` makes the problem satisfiable and returns `[A = ∃k!0 : k!0 = a1 ∨ k!0 = a2, k = 2]` as a model of the set. I'm not sure if there is a faster approach.

Comment: This is now reported as a z3 issue: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/4700

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I run your program, I get:

```
WARNING: correct handling of finite domains is TBD
WARNING: correct handling of finite domains is TBD
WARNING: correct handling of finite domains is TBD
```

before it starts looping. This is a known issue in the implementation: Z3 cannot really deal with sets that have a finite domain.

Alas, replacing it with an infinite domain doesn't help either. Making this change:

```
A, B = Consts('A B', SetSort(IntSort()))
```

You get:

```
unsat
```

which is clearly bogus. I strongly suspect this is related to the following issue: https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/3854 (In short, the SMTLib frontend does not support `set-has-size`. For whatever reason, they left it in the Python and C/C++ interfaces, but clearly it's not really functional.)

So, strictly speaking, this is a bug. But more realistic answer is that `set-has-size` is no longer supported by z3. You should file an issue at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues so the authors are aware of this problem and perhaps remove it from the API completely if it won't ever be supported.

### UPDATE:

As of this [commit](https://github.com/NikolajBjorner/z3/commit/8a528f51a4f292def3f7633747bbcc5e1264b3ed), z3 no longer accepts the `set-has-size` predicate; it is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks. i was running this from a Jupyter notebook and didn't notice warnings were in the shell (outside of the jupyter web environment). I see the same warnings about TBD.

Comment: Please do file an issue in their tracker so they're aware of this. Incidentally, to solve your original problem over a finite domain, I'd simply use a bunch of booleans for each element that can be in the set, and then assert a pseudo-boolean constant regarding intersections. I think that should have good performance too.